# Automation of export from lightroom to a presentation format (e.g. Powerpoint)

Tags: lightroom, software, automation, presentation, export

I have a few hundred commercial photoshoots in Lightroom Classic organized in a folder structure that follows this format:
[Photoshoot name] => [Product name] => Photo files, some are processed and some are not

I'm looking for a way to automate conversion of the photos to a presentation (ideally PowerPoint). My ideal output would be to have one PPT file per photoshoot, with slides that have the product name as a title, then include all the cropped photos. I'm not really concerned about the layout or the design of the slides, as long as the content is there and labelled correctly.

I looked for any plugins or products that can automate this process but couldn't find anything.

Does anyone know of any way to automate as much of this process as possible?

Comment: This sounds like a better fit for [Graphic Design SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) rather than here at Photography SE. This question asks nothing about how to produce photographs, only how to incorporate them into Power Point presentations.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about how to create or produce photographs, but how to incorporate already existing photographs into PowerPoint presentations.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a command line way to "convert" exported images from Lightroom to PowerPoint slides. This may require a little bit of Windows Batch knowledge.

Google tells me, there is at least one: [P3ICLI (PowerPoint Picture Insert Command Line Interface)](https://p3icli.sourceforge.io/)
If I understand this tool correctly, you may create a PowerPoint template according your needs, that can be filled using this tool later. I didn't try this tool myself, however.

If you managed to create a script to create a slide from your template PPTX file, you can create a Batch file that creates PowerPoint files from the exported images, such as:

```
@echo off
echo running...
:loop
if /%1/ == // goto endloop
echo Processing %1...
if exist %1 call convert-to-pptx.bat %1
shift
goto loop
:endloop
echo done.
```

`convert-to-pptx.bat` is then your Batch script that creates a PowerPoint slide from an exported image using P3ICLI.

Save both Batch files in `%AppData%\Adobe\Lightroom\Export Actions`.

Now you can select your Batch file in Lightroom's export dialog in *Post Processing* → *After Export* and save this export preset.

Everytime you export files using this preset PowerPoint slides should be created from your exported images.

Answer (score 0):

If Powerpoint is not a hard requirement, you could use the [Lightroom Slideshow feature](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom-classic/help/creating-slide-shows-basic-workflow.html) and export the result to a PDF.

In the slideshow you can add [metadata of each photo](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom-classic/help/adding-overlays-slides.html#add_text_and_metadata_to_slides) on the slide. This metadata includes the name of the folder the photo resides in (which is the product name in your case).